# Form error in javascript game

Tags: javascript, forms

Okay so I'm working on this little RPG game thing in javascript and I'm using a drop down menu to display the inventory. Basically it loops through the inventory array and the item has a quantity of greater than one, it adds it to the inventory form. The only problem is that when an item has a quantity of 0 (It shouldn't appear in the inventory form), it just shows a white space wherever the item would go if it had a quantity of over 0. How do I make it so it only shows the item with a quantity of over 0? Any help is appreciated and more code available on demand.

```
function page_inventory(){
    document.getElementById('everything').innerHTML = '<span id="inv"><select name="stuff" id="current"></select><button onclick="equip_wep()">Equip</button></span>';

    for (i=0;i<you.inv.length;i++) {
        if (you.inv[i].quantity>0) {
            current.options[0] =new Option(you.inv[i].name+" X"+ you.inv[i].quantity,i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: now what is happening

Comment: also share the html and `you.inv`. Also share how `page_inventory()` is invoked

Comment: is possible create a demo problem at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on jsFiddle for some reason, but you can go to danman113.vacau.com/RPGtest1(WIP).html to see it in action. As for what is happening, basically this function is executed when the user pushes a button in the menu that takes him to the inventory page. This function shows the inventory page, which at this point is just a drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function page_inventory(){
    document.getElementById('everything').innerHTML = '<span id="inv"><select name="stuff" id="current"></select><button onclick="equip_wep()">Equip</button></span>';

    for (i=0;i < current.options.length; i++) {
        current.options[i] = null;
    }

    for (i=0; i < you.inv.length; i++) {
        if (you.inv[i].quantity>0) {
            current.options[i] =new Option(you.inv[i].name+" X"+ you.inv[i].quantity,i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but no such luck. Thanks a ton for the effort though!